# The provided file is not a valid IStorage

Tags: c#, msg

I'm working on an application to log the contents of some .msg files into an SQL Database.

The .msg files are from an SMSserver too, just for some added factors to the issue I'm having.

Every time I run the script on the server I get "The provided file is not a valid IStorage", google seems to be fruitless for this issue and it's driving me mad!

i'm using this library too: https://github.com/Sicos1977/MSGReader

```
using MsgReader.Outlook;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace OutboxSMS
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PostmsgtoSQL();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static bool Filecreated = true;

    public static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Filecreated = true;
    }

    public static void PostmsgtoSQL()
    {
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\ProgramData\\Felltech Ltd\\OutboxSMSXX\\SMSTextSent");
        var myFile = directory.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
        var filepath = myFile.ToString();

        //File System Watching
        FileSystemWatcher FSW = new FileSystemWatcher(directory.ToString(), ".log");
        FSW.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        FSW.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        //below is broken :<
        using (var msg = new Storage.Message(@filepath))
        {
            //Grab .msg headers
            var Id = msg.Id;
            var datetime = msg.CreationTime;
            var from = msg.Sender;
            var sentOn = msg.SentOn;
            var recipientsTo = msg.GetEmailRecipients(Storage.Recipient.RecipientType.To, false, false);
            var subject = msg.Subject;
            var messagebody = msg.BodyRtf;
            //broken to here
            if (Filecreated == true)
            {
                //SQL Wizardry
                SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection();
                db.ConnectionString = "Server=Dev-SQL;Database=AshTest;Trusted_Connection=true";
                String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.SMSLog (ID,toaddress,fromaddress,subject,datetime,messagebody) VALUES(@Id,@toaddress,@fromaddress, @subject, @datetime.)";
                db.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, db);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Id);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toaddress", recipientsTo);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromaddress", from);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", subject);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime", datetime);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@messagebody", messagebody);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                db.Close();
                db.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There's likely a problem with your file. Is it really an OLE storage file (*.msg)? Because there's no arguing with the [`StgIsStorageFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380334(v=vs.85).aspx) method. I'm a bit concerned that your directory is named `SMSTextSent` as SMS and OLE storage files are completely different.

Comment: @DanWilson Yeah, they're .msg files. The SMS server used SMTP to SMS to send out the texts, so they get saves as .msg files.

Comment: Post the [redacted] contents of your file. I'm curious about the format.

Comment: I'm still rather new to programming, I havent Redacted anything from the file to my knowlege... @DanWilson

Comment: Post one of your message files in this question, while removing or obfuscating any sensitive data. I'm interesting in seeing the file structure.

Comment: Hi, The Msg reads like this:

   ` {id:START}`
$USER_ID
{id:END}
{toaddress:START}
$USER_PHONENUMBER
{toaddress:END}
{fromaddress:START}


{fromaddress:END}
{datetime:START}
2015-11-27 11:54:54
{datetime:END}
{receipt:START}
{receipt:END}
{source:START stream=csv}

{source:END}
{messagebody:START type=text charset=8859-1}
MESSAGEBODY
{messagebody:END}`

Comment: I'm not sure what format that is, but it doesn't look correct. Save a message from Outlook, view the contents in an editor, and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

This library calls the `StgIsStorageFile` methods but discards the result. Change the two lines looking like this one in the library:

```
if (NativeMethods.StgIsStorageFile(storageFilePath) != 0)
{
   throw new ArgumentException("The provided file is not a valid IStorage", "storageFilePath");
}
```

for something like:

```
int result = NativeMethods.StgIsStorageFile(storageFilePath);
if (result != 0)
{
   throw new ArgumentException($"The provided file is not a valid IStorage. Result={result}", "storageFilePath");
}
```

Return values are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/coml2api/nf-coml2api-stgisstoragefile) and should help you finding what's going on.